# Working with RC Integrator and RC Differentiator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, dc, integrator

I am working with a simple RC circuit, where I am studying RC differentiator and RC integrator, applied to step DC voltage. But, what I need to know is, I have learnt that during the response of RC differentiator, the frequency of the function generator needs to be lower, such that it produces a time period \$T\$ that is greater than the time constant \$\tau=RC\$ of the circuit in terms of magnitude. But I do not understand why. In fact, mathematically, there is no such indication that resembles the practical issue that \$\tau\$ needs to be less than \$T\$ in terms of magnitude to work with.

Similarly, in the case of RC integrator, we find that \$\tau>T\$ to work with. But why is the case? I need to interpret the physical significance of these two conditions: why do they behave like that. I know the mathematical equations governing these two systems, but I could not grasp the situation going on here.

Secondly, I have another issue to solve. Consider I am passing DC current into my circuit and observing the output as the voltage across the resistance, is there any possibility that there is a phase difference between the input and the output? If there is, can they be explained mathematically?

Comment: Let's start with the differentiator. Since I must use my crystal ball and read your mind, I'll guess that the input is a square wave with a fast rise and fall time at least 1000 times shorter than its period and that a C couples this to a grounded R and you are looking at the non-grounded end of R as the output. (You could just have shown me. But oh well.) Both ends of the C will be jerked up by a rising edge and jerked down by a falling edge. In between, the R will alternately charge the C. If R is small enough (fast enough) then you will see a spike. If not, only an RC curve between.

Comment: By the way, you say *"mathematically, there is no such indication"*. Show me the math that justifies that statement.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, it is not possible to realize the IDEAL function of an intergator resp. differentiator. In detail:

**Integrator**: The ideal function H(s)=1/sT can only be approximated using an opamp (open-loop gain Ao) and a capacitor C (in the feedback path) leading to the transfer function (classical inverting Miller integrator):

**H(s)=-[Ao/(1+sRC)] / [1 + Ao*sRC/(1+sRC)].**

- **case 1** (s=jw=0): The transfer function approaches the finite value -Ao(w=0)=-Aoo
- **case 2** (ideal opamp Ao infinite): The transfer function can be simplified to
  H(s)=-1/sRC.
- **case 3** (frequencies w>>1/RC): The function can be simplified to
  H(s)=-[1/sRC]/[1+(1/Ao)].

**Evaluation**: Only in case of an ideal opamp the (idealized) transfer function equals the (ideal) integrator function. The best approach (case 3) requires that the operatimg (angular) frequencies are much larger than the "cross-over" (angular) frequency: **w>>1/RC**. In reality the situation is even worse because the above functions contain only the finite open-loop gain Ao of the opamp, which in fact is frequency dependent Ao(jw) and, hence, causes additional phase shifts.

**Comment 1 :** The calacualtions above are based on a Miller intergator with a pure capacitor in the feedback path. This is allowed when the device is part of an overall negative feedback loop (typical case: control system). However, in all other cases, the opamps non-idealities (offset) require in addition a DC-stabilizing feedback resistor Rf in parallel to the feedback capacitor.

As a result, the overall transfer function will be a typical lowpass function having a simplified transfer function (ideal opamp with Ao approaching infinity):
**H(s)=-(Rf/R)/[1+sRf*C)]**

In this case, a "good" (however, not ideal) integrating operation requires that **w>>(1/Rf*C)**.

**Comment 2:** The above considerations are valid in principle also to all other opamp-based integrating devices (BTC-integrator, Deboo integrator,..)

**Comment 3**: For a differentiating opamp-based circuit some similar considerations are possible.

Comment: is there any way to explain the answer without any reference to op amp? I am not introduced to it yet.

Comment: @M.Riyan Without some form of feedback amplifier, you're even further from ideal, and "integrator" and "differentiator" cease to be useful ways of thinking about things compared to "low pass filter" and "high pass filter".

Comment: @M.Riyan See my answer under EDIT: